# Regular expression with specific word boundary

Tags: c#, regex, word-boundary

Let's say I have a string of type

> (Price+Discounted_Price)*2-Max.Price

and a dictionary containing what to replace for each element

> Price: A1  Discounted_Price: A2 Max.Price:A3

How can I replace exactly each phrases, without touching the other. Meaning search for `Price` should not modify `Price` in `Discounted_Price`. The result should be `(A1+A2)*2-A3` and not `(A1+Discounted_A1) - Max.A1` or anything else

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variables can consist of alphanumeric/underscore/dot characters, you can match them with `[\w.]+` regex pattern, and add boundaries that include `.`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "(Price+Discounted_Price)*2-Max.Price";
        var dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dct.Add("Price", "A1");
        dct.Add("Discounted_Price", "A2");
        dct.Add("Max.Price","A3");
        var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<![\w.])[\w.]+(?![\w.])",     // Find all matches with the regex inside s
            x => dct.ContainsKey(x.Value) ?   // Does the dictionary contain the key that equals the matched text?
                  dct[x.Value] :              // Use the value for the key if it is present to replace current match
                  x.Value);                   // Otherwise, insert the match found back into the result
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/0oemxG)

The `(?<![\w.])` negative lookbehind fails the match if the match is preceded with a word or a dot char, and the `(?![\w.])` negative lookahead will fail the match if it is followed with a word or dot char.

Note that `[\w.]+` allows a dot in the leading and trailing positions, thus, you might want to replace it with `\w+(?:\.\w+)*` and use as `@"(?<![\w.])\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?![\w.])"`.

**UPDATE**

Since you have already extracted the keywords to replace  as a list, you need to use a more sophisticated word boundary excluding dots:

```
var listAbove = new List<string> { "Price", "Discounted_Price", "Max.Price" };
var result = s;
foreach (string phrase in listAbove)
{
    result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\b(?<![\w.])" + Regex.Escape(phrase) +  @"\b(?![\w.])", dct[phrase]);
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/prCS8T).

Comment: I don't quite get the lambda x => dct.ContainsKey(x.Value) ?  dct[x.Value] : x.Value in dictionary. Also it throw a compilation error "Cannot convert lambda to type "int" because it is not a delegate type". Could we somehow rewrite it to a more understandable way for later code maintainer ? Thanks

Comment: Why `int`? Please provide your input data as they are in the question and a;;  your relevant your code, too. As you can see on IDEONE, my code can compile and works well. Are you using a static `Regex.Replace`, or an `Regex` object `Replace` method?

Comment: I added explanations of the lambda to the code in the question.

Comment: My bad. Because it seems my colleague seems to do as followed : put a parser to try to extract each phrase (Price, Discounted_Price, Max.Price) and loop through all of them, foreach (String phrase in listAbove) {result = Regex(inStr, phrase, dic[phrase])}. I don't think the parser works; I'll have to look into his code.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the if expression. What I was asking is how can we put a lambda as replace value. Will it act on each match of inside a group of () ?

Comment: Ok, I see. If you need to actually extract these phrases and replace, you can pass a method instead of the lambda to collect the matches into some "global" variable, and replace accordingly, or you can use my approach. `Regex.Replace` replaces all non-overlapping matches with the replacement pattern. Now, `@"(?<![\w.])[\w.]+(?![\w.])"` regex does not care if anything is inside the `()` or not.

Comment: I don't have his code at the moment. Assume that his parser is correct, how can I replace exactly the phrase ?
foreach (String phrase in listAbove){result = //replace exact phrase only  ?} to replace only the exact match of phrase only ?

Comment: You're the boss. Thanks a bunch Wiktor.

Answer (score 0):

For word boundaries, you can use \b
Use: \bPrice\b

But this will replace Price in Max.Price.

Maybe you want to use regular string replace with:

"Price+" --> A1 + "+"

Example:

```
string test = "(Price+Discounted_Price)*2-Max.Price";
string a1 = "7";
string a2 = "3";
string a3 = "4";

test = test.Replace("(Price", "(" + a1);
test = test.Replace("Discounted_Price", a2);
test = test.Replace("Max.Price", a3);
```

Result:

test is: (7+3)*2-4